# adding global gap for using woodwing diagrams

Tags: notation

Courtesy to Aaron answer, I did re-write my code and it compiled without any erors or wornings - great.
I wonder if it can be use global variable **\pad** instead of using it for each tone as I  wrote:

d4\fre**\pad** d8\fsol**\pad** g4\fdo**\pad** c4\fdo**\pad** c4\fsol**\pad** g4\fsol**\pad**

please, see the rivised code:

```
\version "2.22.1"
```

% this is my first score
\language "english"
\header {
title = "Aint Necessarily So"
%composer = " "
subtitle = "Bronski Beat"
} %/ end header

%%%%%%%%% Function Declarations
fdo = _
\markup {
\center-column {
\override #'(size . 0.7) {
\woodwind-diagram #'flute  #'((cc . (oneF two three four five six))
(lh . ())
(rh . ()))
}}}

fre = _
\markup {
\center-column {
\override #'(size . 0.7) {
\woodwind-diagram #'flute  #'((cc . (oneF two three four five))
(lh . ())
(rh . ()))
} } }

fmi = _
\markup {
\center-column {
\override #'(size . 0.7) {
\woodwind-diagram #'flute  #'((cc . (oneF two three five))
(lh . ())
(rh . ()))
} } }

ffa = _
\markup {
\center-column {
\override #'(size . 0.7) {
\woodwind-diagram #'flute  #'((cc . (oneF two five))
(lh . ())
(rh . ()))
} } }

fsol = _
\markup {
\center-column {
\override #'(size . 0.7) {
\woodwind-diagram #'flute  #'((cc . (two five))
(lh . ())
(rh . ()))
} } }

fla = _
\markup {
\center-column {
\override #'(size . 0.7) {
\woodwind-diagram #'flute  #'((cc . (oneF two three four five))
(lh . ())
(rh . ()))
} } }

fsi = _
\markup {
\center-column {
\override #'(size . 0.7)  {
\woodwind-diagram #'flute  #'((cc . (oneF two three four))
(lh . ())
(rh . ()))

} } }

pad = \once \override TextScript.padding = #4

\relative c'' {
\key g \minor
\numericTimeSignature
\pad
\time 4/4
g8\fdo\pad
d4\fre\pad d8\fsol\pad g4\fdo\pad c4\fdo\pad c4\fsol\pad g4\fsol\pad
b2.\fsi\pad
}

Thanks,
Tommy

Comment: You seem to be using this site to teach you how to use your software. That's what the [manual](https://lilypond.org/manuals.html) is for.

Comment: Why did you remove \pad from the \fdo, \fre, ... definitions?

Comment: That because I did not find answers in manual..

Comment: That becase if I did used them in \fdo, \fre.. definitions a warning just comes again...

Comment: And its changing the woodwing diagrams locations too...

Comment: Well, I tried hard to solved it but I failed....

Answer (score 1):

[image]So, after few more tries I figured out...:

```
\version "2.22.1"

% this is my first score
\language "english"
\header {
   title = "Aint Necessarily So"
   %composer = " "
   subtitle = "Bronski Beat"
} %/ end header

%%%%%%%%% Variables Declaration
%% pad =
%%#(define-music-function
%%     ()
%%     ()
%%   #{
%%     \once \override TextScript.padding = #4
%%   #})

pad = \override TextScript.padding = #4


fdo = _
    \markup {
    \center-column {
    \override #'(size . 0.7) {
    \woodwind-diagram #'flute  #'((cc . (oneF two three four five six))
                                 (lh . ())
                                 (rh . ())) }}} 

fre = _ 
    \markup {
    \center-column {
    \override #'(size . 0.7) {
    \woodwind-diagram #'flute  #'((cc . (oneF two three four five))
                                 (lh . ())
                                 (rh . ())) }}}


fmi = _
    \markup {
    \center-column {
    \override #'(size . 0.7) {
    \woodwind-diagram #'flute  #'((cc . (oneF two three five))
                                 (lh . ())
                                 (rh . ())) }}}

ffa = _
    \markup {
    \center-column {
    \override #'(size . 0.7) {
    \woodwind-diagram #'flute  #'((cc . (oneF two five))
                                 (lh . ())
                                 (rh . ())) }}}

fsol = _
    \markup {
    \center-column {
    \override #'(size . 0.7) {
    \woodwind-diagram #'flute  #'((cc . (two five))
                                 (lh . ())
                                 (rh . ())) }}}

fla = _
    \markup {
    \center-column {
    \override #'(size . 0.7) {
    \woodwind-diagram #'flute  #'((cc . (oneF two three four five))
                                 (lh . ())
                                 (rh . ())) }}}

fsi = _ 
    \markup {
    \center-column { 
    \override #'(size . 0.7)  {
    \woodwind-diagram #'flute  #'((cc . (oneF two three four))
                                 (lh . ())
                                 (rh . ())) }}}


 \relative { 
  \key g \minor 
  \numericTimeSignature
  \tempo "Tempo indication" 8=114
  \time 6/4
  \pad
  \partial 8 % use part of the time
  g'4\fsol
  \pad {d'4\fre d8\fre g,4\fsol c4\fdo c4\fdo g4\fsol} \undo \pad % using group \pad --start and stop for the group...
  %d4\fre d8\fsol g4\fdo c4\fdo c4\fsol g4\fsol
  b2.\fsi c2\fsol b2\fsol g4\fsol f4\fsol g2\fsol
}
```

This I ment to do...
Thanks for all guys

Comment: Can you edit this into your original question so that readers can see your latest attempts?